# Quotations approval odoo v9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

All **quotations** must be approved by **Sales**, **Technical heads** and **GM**. Three departments needs to approve the quotation.
Pls suggest any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Download sale_double_validation module from [Git](https://github.com/Vauxoo/addons-vauxoo/tree/9.0) for Odoo V9.

Comment: Thanks can you explain me about this module

Comment: Please install it and see the features. Than I will explain you if you have any doubt.

Comment: Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: It gives above error while installing it. Actually I am new to odoo just started a week ago dont know much about this